# Android webview not showing images linked in html

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-webview, android-sdcard

I am working with WebView in Android to display a .htm file. 
I am storing the file in a folder in my sdcard. 
The htm file is referring to an image which is pointing to a web location.
Ex:

```
<td colspan="2"><img src="http://www.abc.com/abc.png"/></td>
```

and i am loading the webview as follows

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file://"+sdcardlocation+"ABC.htm");
```

The file is opening correctly but the images are not opening on the emulator when i open the Webview.
Is there any way to fix this issue please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check with internet permission in manifest file

Comment: Oh yes.. I had forgotten to enable it.Its working now.Thanks a lot.